# Find number of grammatical parses for a Chinese sentence using Stanford Parser in NLTK

Tags: python, nltk, stanford-nlp

I'm working on a project to categorize Chinese sentences by reading difficulty, and I want to try the feature: # of grammatically correct parsings (readings) of the sentence.

**ex.** In English, "I hit the man with a ruler" could be either `"I hit [the man with a ruler]"` or `"I hit [the man] with a ruler."` So I would want

```
sentence = ["I","hit","the","man","with","the","ruler"]
print(function(sentence))
```

to print `2`.

I'm working within NLTK's interface to the Stanford's Chinese Parser to try this with Chinese sentences (that have already been tokenized into a List of words). [Stanford NLP's FAQ page](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#h) says that you can obtain multiple parse trees for a single input sentence using the "-printPCFGkBest n" option, and this seems to be a step in the right direction, but
1. I can't figure out how to use this option in NLTK and
2. Is it possible to get all grammatical parses this way?

Comment: Try Developing and Evaluating Chunkers from [this](http://www.nltk.org/book/ch07.html). There is no way of generating different parses for the same sentence in NLTK. There only exists one way to parse the same sentence, it involves generating the most relative chunks. N-grams and Classifier-Based Chunkers are the ways that could help you perform chunking. Perhaps what you are looking for can simply be acheived by counting the various NP (noun phrases) and VP(verb phrases) that occur in a sentence. But that doesn't seem right.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! If I can't find an already existing function or library, I'll try this kind of more manual approach. But since I'm working with the Stanford Parser, and their [FAQ](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/parser-faq.shtml#h) indicates that there's a means of getting multiple parses, I still have hope that there's a way to use that in Python.